# Log to %AllUsersProfile% folder with Nlog 1.0

Tags: file, nlog, logging

I want my logging to go into the %AllUsersProfile% folder (or a subfolder of it...)

I'm using NLog 1.0 and seems like the website wiki has holes in it as they are upgrading their documentation for their 2.0 release.

I'm using Win7 and tried the following:

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${%AllUsersProfile%}\Logs\${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd_(HH)}_(pid-${processid}).htm">
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${%AllUsersProfile}\Logs\${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd_(HH)}_(pid-${processid}).htm">
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${AllUsersProfile}\Logs\${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd_(HH)}_(pid-${processid}).htm">
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="%AllUsersProfile%\Logs\${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd_(HH)}_(pid-${processid}).htm">
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="%AllUsersProfile\Logs\${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd_(HH)}_(pid-${processid}).htm">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, [specialfolder](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Specialfolder_layout_renderer) does the trick

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}\Logs\${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd_(HH)}_(pid-${processid}).htm">
```